# Change the tabs bar height in guake terminal

Tags: css, terminal

I would like to decrease the tabs bar height in [guake terminal](http://guake.org/).

As said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869701/decrease-the-tabs-bar-height-in-gnome-terminal), this is possible in gnome terminal by editing `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. Is there a similar way to achieve this in guake terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [this git post](https://github.com/Guake/guake/pull/1693). All I did is append the css file in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` with the following:

```
#guake-terminal {
  font-size: 11px;
}

#guake-terminal header box button,
#guake-terminal header box button:hover,
#guake-terminal header box button:hover:backdrop {
    margin-bottom: -100px; /*this is the line that makes buttons disappear.*/
    background: inherit;
    border: inherit;
    padding: inherit;
}

#guake-terminal header tabs tab {
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Note that lines beggining with `#` are not comments in this case.